# How to looping on Treemap chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, treemap

I have a treemap chart code and this is work, displaying treemap chart according to my expectations. But the values still on hard code. I want to looping that as much as the existing data in the database. Using for, while but went I run it, I get an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

This is my code

```
function drawChart(){
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['Location', 'Parent' , 'Size', 'Color'],
                        ['Cabang',null,0,0],
                        [
                        for (i=0; i<0; i++){
                            console.log([dataFromPHP[i].provinsi,'Cabang',0,0],);
                        ],

                        [
                        for (j=0; j<0; j++){
                            console.log([dataFromPHP[j].kode_sales ,dataFromPHP[j].provinsi ,dataFromPHP[j].gaji ,dataFromPHP[j].count],);
                        ], ]);
```

And this is my working code

```
function drawChart(){
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['Location', 'Parent' , 'Size', 'Color'],
                        ['Cabang',null,0,0],
                        [dataFromPHP[0].provinsi,'Cabang',0,0],
                        [dataFromPHP[1].provinsi,'Cabang',0,0],
                        [dataFromPHP[2].provinsi,'Cabang',0,0],
                        [dataFromPHP[0].kode_sales ,dataFromPHP[0].provinsi ,3 ,dataFromPHP[0].count],
                        [dataFromPHP[1].kode_sales ,dataFromPHP[1].provinsi ,1 ,dataFromPHP[1].count],
                        [dataFromPHP[2].kode_sales ,dataFromPHP[2].provinsi ,1 ,dataFromPHP[2].count], ]);
```

What should I do to make a looping values in Treemap format? Thanks in advance

This is my JSON file

```
[
{
    "provinsi": "Jawa Tengah",
    "pulau": "Jawa",
    "kode_sales": "SAL04",
    "gaji": "913",
    "count": "3"
},
{
    "provinsi": "Jawa Barat",
    "pulau": "Jawa",
    "kode_sales": "CLI02",
    "gaji": "500",
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "provinsi": "Jawa Timur",
    "pulau": "Jawa",
    "kode_sales": "SAL99",
    "gaji": "125",
    "count": "1"
}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you must complete one statement before starting another

can't have a `for` loop in the middle of `arrayToDataTable`

as for `for` loop, this will never run --> `for (i=0; i<0; i++){`

`i` starts at `0`, and should run as long as `i < 0` -- so it ends immed

try this...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Location', 'Parent' , 'Size', 'Color'],
  ['Cabang', null, 0, 0]
]);

for (var i = 0; i < dataFromPHP.length; i++) {
  data.addRow([dataFromPHP[i].provinsi, 'Cabang', 0, 0]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < dataFromPHP.length; i++) {
  data.addRow([dataFromPHP[i].kode_sales, dataFromPHP[i].provinsi, dataFromPHP[i].gaji, dataFromPHP[i].count]);
}
```

**EDIT**

instead of using `arrayToDataTable`, define the DataTable explicitly
to ensure the correct types are used

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
data.addColumn('string', 'Parent');
data.addColumn('number', 'Size');
data.addColumn('number', 'Color');

data.addRow(['Cabang', null, 0, 0]);

for (var i = 0; i < dataFromPHP.length; i++) {
  data.addRow([dataFromPHP[i].provinsi, 'Cabang', 0, 0]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < dataFromPHP.length; i++) {
  data.addRow([dataFromPHP[i].kode_sales, dataFromPHP[i].provinsi, dataFromPHP[i].gaji, dataFromPHP[i].count]);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

since the numbers are stored as strings in the JSON,
wrap numbers in `parseFloat` (floating precision) or `parseInt` (integer)

e.g. --> `parseFloat(dataFromPHP[i].gaji)`

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataFromPHP.length; i++) {
  data.addRow([dataFromPHP[i].kode_sales, dataFromPHP[i].provinsi, parseFloat(dataFromPHP[i].gaji), parseInt(dataFromPHP[i].count)]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @WhiteHat :) I already try it and get error "Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 913 does not match type number in column index 2". Can you explain me whats the problem?

Comment: ahh I know the problem... from the second for I have dataFromPHP[i].gaji.. but if I run it, that code didn't show a number variable.. I already testing it with hard code number, it's always show up, but if I wrote dataFromPHP[i].gaji or count always error.. Why that cannot be read by number?

Comment: COOL!! It's solved my big problem!! Woahh I.m very grateful to you @WhiteHat :')